# Microformat oomph.js breaks rest of my JS

Tags: javascript, microformats

I'm writing a little webpage that displays some Flickr photos and also includes microformats using oomph.js. I have bit of JS and when I run the code without `<script type='text/javascript' src="oomph.js"></script>` the code runs fine (all my photos are loaded. However, when I add in the above script tag, my photos don't load.

Here is my broke JS (doesn't show photos):

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="jquery-1.6.3.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="oomph.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

var ajaxURL="http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/groups_pool.gne?id=626753@N20&lang=en-us&format=json&jsoncallback=?"; 
$.getJSON(ajaxURL,function(data) {
    $('h1').text(data.title);
    $.each(data.items,function(i,photo) {
        var photoHTML = '<span class="image">';
        photoHTML += '<a href="' + photo.link + '">';
        photoHTML += '<img src="' + photo.media.m.replace('_m','_s') + '"></a>';
        $('#photos').append(photoHTML);
    }); // end each
}); // end get JSON

}); // end ready
</script>
```

and here is the code that works (shows photos):

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="jquery-1.6.3.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

var ajaxURL="http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/groups_pool.gne?id=626753@N20&lang=en-us&format=json&jsoncallback=?"; 
$.getJSON(ajaxURL,function(data) {
    $('h1').text(data.title);
    $.each(data.items,function(i,photo) {
        var photoHTML = '<span class="image">';
        photoHTML += '<a href="' + photo.link + '">';
        photoHTML += '<img src="' + photo.media.m.replace('_m','_s') + '"></a>';
        $('#photos').append(photoHTML);
    }); // end each
}); // end get JSON

}); // end ready
</script>
```

I've browsed the internet and have yet to find a solution. If anyone could shed some light on this issue I would greatly appreciate it :-).

Comment: anything in the console?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, this is in the console `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getJSON' of undefined` followed by `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)` a couple times

Comment: Could you replicate this in a fiddle? Are you sure this snippet is exactly as it is in your broken code?

Comment: Could you give us the url of the resource that fail to load?

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getJSON' of undefined lab6_dthiemann.html:15
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://visitmix.com/university/stories3/oomph/images/yahoo.png
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://visitmix.com/university/stories3/oomph/images/apple.png
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://visitmix.com/university/stories3/oomph/images/outlook.png`

Comment: I don't know this lib, but even examples on their site are broken. I think you should avoid using it. It seems that it alter jQuery namespace. Make sure the version of jQuery you are using is the one excpected by `oomph.js`.

Comment: Ok thanks! The issue is its for a homework assignment, I'll talk to my professor about it.

Comment: I was able to fix it by including an older version of JQuery (version 1.3.2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue by including an older version of JQuery (version 1.3.2)